# Why doesn't my code properly parse this XML file?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml log file in PHP. It has following structure

```
 <log>
 <logentry revision="1745">
 <author>abc</author> 
  <date>2010-08-31T20:46:29.691125Z</date> 
 <paths>
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/abc.java</path> 
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/test.java</path> 
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/xmltest.java</path> 
  </paths>
  <msg>how to make it work!</msg> 
  </logentry>
</log>
```

How can I extract all data from this xml file? How can loop on log file to extract all data? I want to get that M from action as well.

I tried this code as well, but I couldn't make it work for whole file.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.log");

echo $xml->getName();


foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: @user431276 - First answer already show you how to use simplexml ...

Comment: Why do you not copy RageZ's code? You seem to have left out `$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`simplexml`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) for that purpose

```
$xmlStr = <<<XML
<log>
 <logentry revision="1745">
 <author>abc</author> 
  <date>2010-08-31T20:46:29.691125Z</date> 
 <paths>
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/abc.java</path> 
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/test.java</path> 
  <path kind="" action="M">/trunk/myserver/xmltest.java</path> 
  </paths>
  <msg>how to make it work!</msg> 
  </logentry>
</log>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
foreach($xml->logentry as $entry){
   echo "revision: {$entry['revision']}" . PHP_EOL;
   echo "author: {$entry->author}" . PHP_EOL;
   echo "paths:" . PHP_EOL;
   foreach($entry->paths->path as $pa){
     echo "\t kind: {$pa['kind']} action: {$pa['action']} path: {$pa}" . PHP_EOL;
   }
   echo "message: {$entry->msg}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use use "<br />", instead of PHP_EOL. Also "<pre>" . "\t....". Otherwise it does not display as expected in the browser.

Comment: @Geoffrey: actually my attend was for a script running on CLI ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.